# Função upper e Lower case

Tags: ionic, typescript

Bom dia, estou tentando fazer dois métodos, um para uppercase e outro lower, porém não estou conseguindo com typescritp e ionic, segue o código:

Gostaria que ao clicar em upper, o texto fosse enviado em maiusculo para a outra página e vice-versa.

Typescript

```
import { TestePage } from './../teste/teste';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Clipboard } from '@ionic-native/clipboard';
import { Element } from '@angular/compiler';

/**
 * Generated class for the ResultPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({

  selector: 'page-result',
  templateUrl: 'result.html',
})
export class ResultPage {
  private todo : FormGroup;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
    ) {
      this.todo = this.formBuilder.group({
        title: ['', Validators.required]
      });


  }


  form: any ={
    texto: "" //this.todo.value.title
    }
 upper(){
   this.navCtrl.push(TestePage, {
     texto: this.todo.value.title

   })
}

lower(){
  this.navCtrl.push(TestePage, {
    texto: this.todo.value.title 
  })
}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ResultPage');
  }

}
```

html:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>result</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <!--

-->
      <form id="form" [formGroup]="todo" (ngSubmit)="logForm()">
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label></ion-label>
            <ion-input  type="text" formControlName="title"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>



        </form>
        <button (click)="upper()" id="btn" ion-button type="submit" >01</button>
        <button (click)="lower()" id="btn" ion-button type="submit" >02</button>

    </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você quer enviar os textos em maiúsculo e minusculo mas não está transformando esses textos, para isso, use as funções nativas do JavaScript para manipular textos, ficando assim:

```
upper(){
   this.navCtrl.push(TestePage, {
     // toUpperCase faz com que todo o texto fique em maiúsculo
     texto: this.todo.value.title.toUpperCase()
   })
}

lower(){
  this.navCtrl.push(TestePage, {
    // toLowerCase faz com que todo o texto fique em minusculo
    texto: this.todo.value.title.toLowerCase()
  })
}
```

Comment: Tão simples e não encontrava nada na internet, Obrigado !!